# Update JSF components in sequence from bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the need to execute three actions one another from my backing bean but the second and third ones seems to be fired before the first one finish executing.

The result is that the second/third action is called but not executed.

How do I manage to execute the first action, wait until if finishes and than start the second/third action?

**Actions are**

1. Close a modal dialog window. This take up to a second to execute the rendering.

> RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlgConfirmApplicationDelete').hide();");

2. Update a panel `h:panelGroup` component

> RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("j_idt3:panelGroupHolder");

3. Update a second panel `h:panelGroup` component

> RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("j_idt3:center_westBody");

Comment: why not use just a separate method with a boolean access or something like this ???

Comment: are you waiting the user OK to execute the second action ?!?

Comment: Not waiting for the user. After the user click the button on the dialog window, I need to perform an action in the database and depending on the result I need to close the window and right after update the other two panelGroups with the updated information.

Comment: did you try something ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to perform an action in the database and depending on the
>   result I need to close the window and right after update the other two
>   panelGroups with the updated information

You could do this without calling actions from java code.

Without knowing your exact layout, the task you are asking for would usually look like this:

```
<p:commandLink 
   process="@form" 
   actionListener="#{bean1.updateDatabase}"   
   update="j_idt3:panelGroupHolde;j_idt3:center_westBody" 
   oncomplete="if (args.updateSuccessfull) PF('dlgConfirmApplicationDelete').hide();">
```

and inside your `bean1.updateDatabase` method, you specify `args.updateSuccessfull` depending on the actual result of the query.

```
Boolean updateSuccessfull = false;
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("updateSuccessfull", updateSuccessfull);
```

In the example you mentioned the order is not important, as each action will have it's predetermined outcome and is dedicated to a certain phase in the life-cycle (update always comes before oncomplete):

- If the update-query fails, data does not change, so the `update=` has no impact and the dialog stays visible due to the CallBack-Param.
- If the update-query works, data does change, both ui-elements are updated (where order must not matter) and the dialog is hidden due to the CallBack-Param.

If this is not the case, then you have code inside the `RenderResponse`-Phase, which should rather be executed in the `InvokeApplication`-Phase (or earlier).

A common misstake causing the later is to call "methods containing heavy code" from the xhtml (while other listings ("second update") depend on that values as well), like

`<ui:repeat values="#{bean1.queryDatabaseForXY()}" ...>`

Obviously now the SECOND update needs to come after the first update, cause it also requires some data from `bean1.queryDatabaseForXY()`.

Rather than that you should perform data loading and/or calculations in the proper phase and simply refer to a `getter` returning an already known collection when generating the response:

```
<ui:repeat values="#{bean1.getUsers()}" ...>
```

or more precicesly

```
    <ui:repeat values="#{bean1.users}" ...>
```

(The actual loading would be either `@PostConstruct`, an `<f:viewAction>` or just the already existing list inside a view- or session-scoped bean)

Comment: Hi Dognose! Thanks a lot for sharing this solution. Primefaces really rocks!! Using such great features make coding much simpler.